# Copy a public gdrive file to my account with curl

Tags: powershell, curl

I tried to copy public gdrive files to my account by Gdrive API with a simple ps1 script and unix-tools for windows. (curl).
Worked out all required tokens and started to copy,download,delete files that I copied before.
The problem is, I found out that public shared files have different permissions

> "capabilities": {   "canCopy": true,   "canEdit": false  }, 
>   "editable": false,  "copyable": true,

like this link for example:

drive.google.com/open?id=1ArIfiMSmBdlZQUm1cgHi8RRjhSCh8Rym

This is working fine by api request, but if I try to copy files with this permissions

> "capabilities": {   "canCopy": **false**,   "canEdit": false  }, 
>   "editable": false,  "copyable": **false**,

drive.google.com/open?id=1cHAsF0D8zEp3LbVB4LmEQbJ3LdU8Cj7i

I get:

```
"reason": "forbidden",
"message": "Insufficient permissions for the specified parent.",
"locationType": "other",
"location": "parent.permissions" }],
```

"code": 403,
  "message": "Insufficient permissions for the specified parent."
 }
}

*But in my browser I can rightclick taht file and simply make a copy.
So it seems just not possible by api requests.
But how can I do that by curl/http requests (with stored cookie or someting) ?*

> $UID = 'clientID.apps.googleusercontent.com'
>
> $skey = 'clientsecret'
>
> $readtoken = (Get-Content "$PSScriptRoot\refreshtoken.txt")
>
> This is to create a fresh accesstoken from stored refreshtoken
>
> $token = curl -d
>   "client_id=$UID&client_secret=$skey&refresh_token=$readtoken&grant_type=refresh_token"
>   https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token | grep access_token
>
> $string = $token.TrimStart("`"access_token`": `"")
>
> $cleantoken = $string.TrimEnd("`",")
>
> $drivefile = Read-Host -Prompt 'Put your Link here' 
>   $driveID =
>   $drivefile.Substring(33)
>
> $LINKS = curl --request POST
>   "https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v2/files/$driveID/copy" --header
>   "Authorization: Bearer $cleantoken" --header "Accept:
>   application/json" --header "Content-Type: application/json" --data
>   "{}" --compressed

Comment: `curl` is just an alias for `Invoke-Webrequest` to really use curl somewhere in the path use `curl.exe` (In recent Win10 versions curl.exe is installed) See `Get-Command curl*`

Comment: ah yes sry I was not clear enough. i use already curl.exe from unix-utils for win

Comment: But **your** code will use the alias not `curl.exe`

Comment: It seems that ``1cHAsF0D8zEp3LbVB4LmEQbJ3LdU8Cj7i`` returns ``"File not found: 1cHAsF0D8zEp3LbVB4LmEQbJ3LdU8Cj7i."``. I have experienced the same situation with you before. At that time, I have resolved by copying the file to the specific folder. I'm not sure about the reason of this. In your case, it uses ``--data "{\"parents\": [\"### folder ID ###\"]}"`` instead of ``--data "{}"``. Because I'm not sure whether this can be used for your situation, I posted this as a comment. If this didn't work, I apologize.

Comment: I thought about the own folder ID too, but get always an parse error